# How to count number of partial occurrences of a string in a file

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a file of which I need to count all partial matches for an input string in a file.
I'll show you an easy example of what I need:

In a file with this content:

```
Good-Black-Cat
Bad-Red-Cat
Bad-Gray-Dog
Good-Golden-Dog
Bad-White-Dog
Good-Tabby-Cat
Bad-Siamese-Cat
```

I need to count how many times does the partial string "Good -*-Cat" (Where * could be anything, it doesn't matter) appears. The expected output count is 2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Given

```
$ cat file
Good-Black-Cat
Bad-Red-Cat
Bad-Gray-Dog
Good-Golden-Dog
Bad-White-Dog
Good-Tabby-Cat
Bad-Siamese-Cat
```

then

```
$ grep -c 'Good-.*-Cat' file
2
```

Note that this is a *count of matching lines* - so for example it won't work for multiple occurrences per line, or for occurrences that span lines.

Alternatively, with `awk`

```
awk '/Good-.*-Cat/ {n++} END {print n}' file
```

---

If you need to match multiple possible occurrences per line, then I'd suggest `perl`:

```
perl -lne '$c += () = /Good-.*?-Cat/g }{ print $c' file
```

where `/Good-.*?-Cat/g` matches *multiple times* (`g`) and non-greedily* (`.*?`) and the `() =` assignment forces the matches to be evaluated in a scalar context so we can add them to the count.

Alternatively, you could use `grep` in perl-comparible regular expression (PCRE) mode (so as to enable the non-greedy modifier), with `-o` to output only the matching portions - then count those with `wc`:

```
grep -Po 'Good-.*?-Cat' file | wc -l
```

---

If you also need to match occurrences that may span a line boundary, then you can do so in `perl` by unsetting the record separator (note: this means that that the whole file is slurped into memory) and adding the `s` regex modifier e.g.

```
perl -0777 -nE '$c += () = /Good-.*?-Cat/gs }{ say $c' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the case there is the need to count multiple occurrences per line, which would be your recommendation? I've tried the awk code and apparently it counts only matching lines as well.

Comment: @RodrigoAndresNavaLara please see updated answer

Answer (score 4):

#### awk, multiple occurences, space-separated

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++ ) count+=match($i,/Good-.*-Cat/)};END{print count}' input.txt
4
$ cat input.txt
Good-Black-Cat
Bad-Red-Cat
Bad-Gray-Dog
Good-Golden-Dog Good-Whatever-Cat Good-Something-Cat
Bad-White-Dog
Good-Tabby-Cat
Bad-Siamese-Cat
```

#### sed + wc, non-multiple occurences

This uses negative pattern matching `//!` with `d` for delete, leaving only lines of interest.

```
$ sed '/Good-.*-Cat/!d' input.txt
Good-Black-Cat
Good-Golden-Dog Good-Whatever-Cat
Good-Tabby-Cat
$ sed '/Good-.*-Cat/!d' input.txt | wc -l
3
```

#### Shell solution, non-multiple occurences

Here's shell way that combines `case...esac` and file-reading loop:

```
$ n=0; while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do case "$line" in "Good-"*"-Cat") n=$((n+1));; esac; done < input.txt; echo "$n"
2
```

Or with indientation

```
n=0
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do 
    case "$line" in 
        "Good-"*"-Cat") n=$((n+1));; 
    esac
done < input.txt
echo "$n"
```

Explanation:

- `n=0` initializes `n` counter variable
- `while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do...done < input.txt` is standard file-reading loop used in shell scripting, with `|| [ -n "$line" ]` protection to account for possible files that don't end in newline
- `case "$line" in "Good-"*"-Cat") n=$((n+1));; esac` pattern-matching for the desired string with `$((...))` arithmetic expansion to increment the counter variable.

Answer (score 3):

## Non-fancy sed/grep version

```
sed 's/\(Good-[^ ]*-Cat\)/XXXX\n/g' input.txt | grep -c XXXX
```

While `XXXX` can be any pattern that does not appear otherwise in your file. This approach replaces all matches with the `XXXX` pattern and a newline, so to make it easily countable by a basic grep expression.

By the way if you take "Where * could be anything" literally, at least to my understanding, the output of any such program would always be 0 or 1, so I am assuming that it should not contain a space at least.